# Swipe to finish Activity pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns

I have seen this pattern on both Tumblr and Telegram apps.

When you are in a detail view (Searching for a Hashtag on Tumblr or in a conversation on Telegram) and swipe from left to right (like if you were going to pull a `Navigation Drawer`) you can see the previous activity come up from there. If you release it, the Activity is finished.

How is this behavior implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any good visual feature, it is a trick :-) .
If you use the UI Automator tool to dump the screen content while in a middle of one of these back slides, you can see that the 'old fragment' is in fact just an image view.
It is only when the slide is finished that the previous fragment/activity is brought from the back stack.
[image: DDMS rules !]

Comment: How can this be done?  How do you make an imageview that is a screenshot of the previous screen?

Comment: @AdamKatz can't be sure .. especially since it was a while ago, but the easiest way to accomplish this would be to get the backing bitmap behind the view when you stop the previous screen.
it Sounds extremely costly memory wise though

Comment: and i need to layer these transitions infinitely, maybe this isnt the best route :(

Comment: well you can't have infinite navigation depth in your app anyway, you would OOM sooner or later.

Comment: Surely facebook does that?  You can click profile, then image, then profile etc etc? Then you can back press through them all?

Comment: that's different.  

Pressing back brings you to the last Activity (or fragment, or fullscreen view in your own backstack, whatever).  

By default the system creates a transition between the 2 screens but does not let you swipe like what is describded in this question.

Answer (score 13):

[Disclaimer: the following dissertation was written after just one hour or so examining Telegram's source code, so it may contain important flaws or mistakes. Feel free to comment]

The case of Telegram looks to be quite different from what Teovald says. In Telegram's case it is not a fixed image. You can check this by having for instance an open chat where someone is writing half swiped. You will see that both the "chat activity" and the "list of chats activity" are updated in real time, which could not be the case if the effect were accomplished by using a static image.

Since Telegram is open sourced, you can have a look at its [code base](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/tree/7545dfe20a42007c93b8e7e1b05b1d6838d001c9) to figure out how it is actually done.

After examining the code myself for a while, it looks like what they do is not a visual trick. In fact, its a trick which goes far beyond doing small trickery to fake some visual effect. Whatever the case, it smells like some non-standard stuff.

First of all, you can have a look at Telegram's manifest file to see that they only define three activities (`LaunchActivity`, `IntroActivity` and `PopupNotificationActivity`)... three activities! Anyone using Telegram would agree that the application seems to have more than three activities, so whatever they are doing it looks like in practice they only have a single activity running at the same time (`LaunchActivity`), which through some mechanism shows different "activity like" content.

Indeed, if you go to `LaunchActivity` you will see that it inherits from a so called `ActionBarActivity`, which would be the base class for all **real** activities in Telegram (although in practice only `LaunchActivity` seems to extend it). This activity seems to take care of implementing, along with other classes, the action bar. Yes, that means that Telegram does not use the standard action bar, nor defines any kind of wrapper to use a "mock" version on Android < 11 and the real version on Android >= 11. It's quite twisted, but you can have a look at their implementation of the action bar (class `ActionBar` as well as other dependent classes) and see that they are literally creating a raw `FrameLayout` and embedding it to emulate the action bar. This means, among other things, that they do not inflate XML resources to define the action bar for each "activity", they populate it by hand instead. Very cumbersome and very non-standard, which in my opinion makes Telegram kind of weak regarding improvements of the action bar in future versions of Android.

Now, the thing that concerns me the most is that they are completely ignoring the Android's activities and fragments system, rolling out their own version. To be precise it's not like they are ignoring Android's activities and fragments altogether, but they are using some techniques that (in my humble opinion) would be frowned upon by probably most of Android developers out there.

If you look at `ActionBarActivity` you will see that it extends a regular Android `Activity`. It removes (via its theme, and also programatically) the standard action bar and title of the activity in the `onCreate()` method (this confirms that they use their own customized version of the action bar). But most importantly, they define a "stack" of "fragments". A "fragment" here is not what one understands by "Android fragment", but some weird version they rolled out too to implement the concept of "fragment". They use the `BaseFragment` class to define a "fragment", which is basically a class that creates its view via a callback (just as Android's fragments do), and which defines some "life cycle" methods such as `onPause()` and `onFragmentDestroy()`. Then you can see that what we would consider to be regular Android activities is actually implemented via this weird mechanism of `BaseFragment`s. For instance, the "chat activity" is implemented by the `ChatActivity` class, however this does not inherit from Android's `Activity`, but from `BaseFragment` instead.

So to summarize what I have explained so far, Telegram seems to be an application running a single activity (`LaunchActivity`, which in turn inherits from `ActionBarActivity`), which implements a customized action bar and a weird "fragment" framework which emulates regular Android activities, at least at the visual level.

Now, if you look at the `onTouchEvent()` method of the `ActionBarActivity` class, this seems to be the one in charge of implementing the core algorithm of the "swipe to dismiss" effect. This tracks the user's finger and moves the view of the fake fragment accordingly. When the user lifts the finger, if the condition to dismiss the "fragment" is true (`backAnimation` is false), the fragment is removed:  when the animation ends, the `onSlideAnimationEnd()` method is called, which will then remove the "fragment" from the fragment stack kept by the `ActionBarActivity` class.

So, in short, Telegram accomplishes the "swipe to dismiss" effect by implementing a funky "fragments" system in which what seems to be an Activity is a raw view modeled via a subclass of `BaseFragment`. This forces them to roll out their own version of the action bar, and also to follow some very weird and "non-standard" Android techniques.

I did not actually know that Telegram was implemented this way, so at this moment I am kind of disappointed. I was expecting them to access some hidden Android APIs, which of course would be wrong, but at least it would not be so cumbersome and ugly as implementing their own action bar and "fragments" system. From now on, to me, Telegram's code will be a reference of what you must not ever do in Android.

Comment: Very informative!. Still holds on this time too. It's still using single Activity called LaunchActivity. But for some reason the app run weirdly smooth on even very low end phones and look superior compared to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented this, check it out here

[SwipeFinishableActivity](https://github.com/enbandari/SwipeFinishableActivity).

Generally speaking, you need a translucent top activity so that when you drag the top activity you can see the second top one below. And you should track your touch event to move your views in your activities.